# What is Application.streamingAssetsPath and manifestBundlePath?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I get the assetbundle by using `UnityWebRequest GetAssetBundle(string uri, uint version, uint crc);`

but `Application.streamingAssetsPath` is empty....

where is downloaded assetbundle and how to loaded downloaded assetbundle?

my Unity version is 2017.3

And add Question.

`AssetBundle manifestBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(manifestBundlePath); AssetBundleManifest manifest = manifestBundle.LoadAsset("AssetBundleManifest");` What is manifestBundlePath and How to access and get this path?

How can I access downloaded assetbundles before use `UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle`

if you suggest the way, I'm really thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html):

> If you have a "StreamingAssets" folder in the Assets folder of your project, it will be copied to your player builds and be present in the path given by Application.streamingAssetsPath.

So presumably if you *do not* have a "StreamingAssets" folder in your Assets folder, then it will be blank.

And for your second question, what is the `manifestBundlePath`, well, again, from [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html):

> **path** - Path of the file on disk.

And you'd get it in the same way as the example:

> `Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "myassetBundle")`

Where `"myassetBundle"` is the name of the bundle.

Similarly when calling `LoadAsset("AssetBundleManifest");`, `"AssetBundleManifest"` is the name of the asset to load.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works; if you are using `GetAssetBundle` then you must load the asset bundle using the response, as the documentation shows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(GetAssetBundle());
    }

    IEnumerator GetAssetBundle() {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle("http://www.my-server.com/myData.unity3d");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {

            // !!!!!! <--- Notice we do not load the asset bundle from file.
            AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to manually download and save the file, do it like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class FileDownloader : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(DownloadFile());
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadFile() {
        var uwr = new UnityWebRequest("http://www.my-server.com/myData.unity3d", UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET);
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "myData.unity3d");
        uwr.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerFile(path);
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
        if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
            Debug.LogError(uwr.error);
        else {
            // !!! <-- Now we have a path to the downloaded asset
            Debug.Log("File successfully downloaded and saved to " + path);
            var myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(path); 

            // Matches some 'Resources/MyObject.prefab'
            var prefab = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAsset.<GameObject>("MyObject");
            Instantiate(prefab);
        }             
    }
}
```